# pct.change between 2 columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, percentage

I have a DataFrame and I am trying to create the 2 day percent return (.pct_change I assume) between two numbers in Column 1 if a condition in another column (Column 2) is true (ie tagged as 1).  I want the output to be placed in a new column within the DataFrame.  If the condition is False (ie a 0) then nothing would get put into the new column.  I would also want the ability to change to calculation time period.  For example change from 2 days to 5 days but I think that can be accomplished with periods override in pct_change

Here is an example

```
Column 1    Column 2    NEW COLUMN      
21.45        0              
21.41        0              
21.52        1          -0.3%   Math >> (21.45/20.52)-1
21.71        0              
20.8         0              
20.35        0          all 0's are blank   
20.44        0  
16.99        0              
17.02        1          20.1%   Math >> (20.44/17.02)-1
16.69        0              
16.03        0              
15.67        0              
15.6         1          2.8%    Math >> (20.44/17.02)-1
15.71        0              
15.48        0
```

Any guidance would really help

Comment: Mathematically, `pct_change` is (current value - previous value)/previous value. You reversed the formula, is that what you want?

Comment: Not entirely.  I am trying to do percent change (from numbers shown in column 1)  when there is a 1 in another column (shown in column 2) but not calculate anything when there is a 0. The percent change would show up in a new column in the DataFrame.  The issue I am struggling with is how to only do the percent change number in the new column when there is a 1 in Column 2.  Thank you

Comment: I actually figured out an answer.  Thought I would post it so that others can see what worked for me.
df['NEW COLUMN'] = np.where(df['Column 2'] == 1, df['Column1'].pct_change(2),0)

of course you also have to import numpy as np